# Where can I catch up on event bubbling in web programming(Esp. RE: the YUI)?

Tags: javascript, events, yui, event-bubbling

Can you provide some good reading material on event-bubbling, especially in regards to the Yahoo User-Interface libraries (YUI) ?

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but Christian Heilmann (Developer Evangelist at Yahoo) has written [some awesome stuff on event delegation using event bubbling and YUI](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/eventdelegation/).